# JS : import remote module with default export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, systemjs

I am trying to create an application with plugins.

What I would like is to be able to import a class from a remote URL (in the format http://www.myscript.com) that has the content

```js
export default class MyClass { ... }
```

And be able to use it in my own code.

What I have achieved so for is using a `<script type="module">` tag that imports the class with success. But it imports it as a "normal" script, in the sense that I can not use `import ... from 'URL';` and thus, I have to give up on the `export` syntax (so I can do a `const x = new MyClass()`).

I need to have the "export" syntax in order to be able to have "anonymous" classes, and create lots of them on the fly.

Is there a way to do it in Javascript ? (It should be noted that actually, I am using Angular + Typescript, but the modules will be written in plain JS)

Comment: using ```type="module"``` does allow you to import the module in the browser, by using for example:
```import * as Module from "www.myscript.com";```

Would this not then work? ```let myModule = new Module.MyClass();``` ....etc (sorry for the pseudo syntax)

Comment: `import * as Module from "www.myscript.com";` seems to not be accepted (Cannot find module 'URL' or its corresponding type declarations). Also, if I do that, I am forced to add those imports at the start of my code, whereas I would like to import them dynamically